# Unable to json_encode array of objects

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP class Country which I return as array of objects from a database function call. I can do var_dump($countries) and see the objects but the equivalent json_encode($countries) returns nothing.

```
class Country implements JsonSerializable{
    private  $id;
    private  $name;

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return (object) get_object_vars($this);
    }

    //Getters and setters
}

//Happening in a function
try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
        $country = new Country();
            $country->setId($row["id"]);
            $country->setName($row["name"]);
        $countries[] = $country;
    }
    $stmt = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //Other stuff
}
error_log(count($countries));          //Returns the actual count (23)  
error_log(json_encode($countries[0])); //Returns the JSON Encoded Country Object {"id":"1","name":"The Name"}
error_log(json_encode($countries));    //Returns NOTHING

error_log(var_dump($countries));       //Returns the dumped array:   array(230) { [0]=> object(Country)#5 (8) { ["id":"Country":private]=> string(1) "1" ["name":"Country":private]=> string(7) "The Name"} [1]=> object(Country)#6 (8) { .............}}
```

My problem is I need to return JSON Encoded list of countries but json_encode($countries) return NOTHING. However, others logs returns as expected. Please friends what could be the issue?

Comment: Check [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php), which will return one of the `JSON_ERROR_*` constants' values.

Comment: Wondering if the fact that each `Country` object appears to be private is to blame. Have you tried changing the visibility?

Comment: @vch Notice that I was able to return the object at index 0 without error

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski json_last_error() returns just 5. What could that imply?

Comment: Currently, `5` represents `JSON_ERROR_UTF8` -- i.e. an encoding issue.

Comment: Since you're getting an encoding issue, I would recommend looping over `$countries` and attempting to `json_encode()` each one individually as you did with `[0]` to debug which one is failing.

Comment: Yeah! You are right @ialarmedalien I used json_last_error_msg() and got "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded". I think it might be coming from the characters saved in my database table. I remember the records where imported

Comment: FIXED!!! I followed @MichaelBerkowski advice. Hence I discovered that it countries name contains characters like:  éáóüåíúá which breaks JSON Encoding. But I wonder how I could have done this on a table with millions of records. Meanwhile, I appreciate all your efforts.

Comment: @Paullo You should post your own answer with how you solved it.

Comment: Okay, I will do that right away

Comment: JSON is fully Unicode-capable, but it expects strings to have UTF-8 as encoding. That means that it *can* encode éáóüåíúá, provided it gets them in the right format. Check your database's encoding, if that is some codepage, you need to convert it to UTF-8 instead.

Comment: That is interesting @UlrichEckhardt "That means that it can encode éáóüåíúá, provided it gets them in the right format". I really do not have much knowledge about different encoding and probably how to check the current database encoding. I could have loved to print the character as they were in the database including éáóüåíúá. But I think I followed the route I did because that is the only thing I knew I can do the be able to JSON Encode. Any alternative solution that can allow me print the characters as they are will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to acknowledge the fact I wouldn't have had this answer without @MichaelBerkowski and @ialarmedalien advice.

Firstly, the problem originated from the source of the record which was imported into MySQL. I don't really know what character encoding that was used on the source record but I am sure it is not "UTF-8 characters".

According @MichaelBerkowski advice logged json_last_error() and json_last_error_msg() after attempting to encode the list of objects returned from the database:

```
error_log(json_encode($countries)); //Return NOTHING
error_log(json_last_error()); //Returns 5
error_log(json_last_error_msg()); Return "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" which explains what the problem is
```

Debugging:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
    $country = new Country();
        $country->setId($row["id"]);
        $country->setName($row["name"]);
        error_log($row['id']."  ::: ".json_encode($country));
    $countries[] = $country;
}

[Sun Aug 24 13:52:28.357533 2014] [:error] [pid 11319] [client 127.0.0.1:41112] 10: {"id":"10","name":"The Name"}
[Sun Aug 24 13:52:28.357662 2014] [:error] [pid 11319] [client 127.0.0.1:41112] 11: 
[Sun Aug 24 13:52:28.357773 2014] [:error] [pid 11319] [client 127.0.0.1:41112] 12: {"id":"12","name":"The Name"}
```

Finally the lines with only the id value are the lines that are causing the problem hence, I used the id value to manually check the database columns and replace strings like éáóüåíúá which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a single qoutes in your string section, you need to first escape it using str_replace like this

```
$newstr =str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $myString);
```

After it do json_encode

```
json_encode($newstring, true);
```

Hope it will resolve the problem.